# problem adding attribute using XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

#### Please note the very last comment: The OP just forgot to call `Save()`.

---

I am checking XML for attribute **ProductCount** under **ProductDetails** node, and if the attribute is not present add the attribute with a default value under this node.

I am able to check if the attribute exists or not but I am not able to add it, though it does not give me any error but does not even add the attribiute.

here is my code:

```
 XDocument XMLDoc = XDocument.Load(fileName);

 foreach (var detail in XMLDoc.Descendants(_ns + "ProductDetails"))
 {
    if (detail.Attribute("ProductCount") == null)
    {
        detail.SetAttributeValue("ProductCount", "1");
    }
 }
```

_ns has my namespace.

I am not able to figure out what I am doing wrong, why is it not adding ProductCount attribute if it does not exist.

Comment: My suspect is that the "foreach" doesn't match any element. Could you post a fragment of the source document?
Then, how is defined the _ns variable?

Comment: <productDetails hadSuspension="false" isComplimentary="false" hasFamily1="false" hasFamily2="false" isInsured="false" hasJoint="false"/>

Comment: Your basic code is OK, how do you establish that "it doesn't work"? Did you use a debugger?

Comment: foreach is fine I tested it I searched for the attribute that is in the XML and it was OK, if the attribute is not there it gives null, I even checked that the control goes inside the if statement but it does not add the attribute.

Comment: "productDetails" begins with lower case? In the code you used the upper "P". Always in the snippet you added a namespace: where is in the xml fragment? Are you sure that the enumeration yields some result?

Comment: Fails to reproduce. This code should work, your problem is possibly elsewhere.

Comment: @ Mario the xml fragment is not complete productDetails begins with P sorry about the mistake in the xml fragment, yes the code works I tested it with the attribute in XML and it returned me the results, only it does add the attribute if it is not there.

Answer (score 4):

Try to pass value as integer instead of string like this:

```
detail.SetAttributeValue("ProductCount", 1);
```

EDIT: wrote bad suggestion...but I tried to test your problem...

created a.xml file with content:

```
<root>
  <ProductDetails hadSuspension="false" isComplimentary="false" hasFamily1="false" hasFamily2="false" isInsured="false" hasJoint="false" ProductCount="1"/>
  <ProductDetails hadSuspension="false" isComplimentary="false" hasFamily1="false" hasFamily2="false" isInsured="false" hasJoint="false"/>
</root>
```

test code:

```
XDocument XMLDoc = XDocument.Load("C:\\a.xml");

foreach (var detail in XMLDoc.Descendants("ProductDetails"))
{
   //Dont need to check, because SetAttributeValue creates if not exists
   //if(detail.Attribute("ProductCount") == null)
   detail.SetAttributeValue("ProductCount", 2);
}
XMLDoc.Save("C:\\b.xml");
```

and result b.xml file content:

```
<root>
  <ProductDetails hadSuspension="false" isComplimentary="false" hasFamily1="false" hasFamily2="false" isInsured="false" hasJoint="false" ProductCount="2" />
  <ProductDetails hadSuspension="false" isComplimentary="false" hasFamily1="false" hasFamily2="false" isInsured="false" hasJoint="false" ProductCount="2" />
</root>
```

So everything is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (detail.Attribute("ProductCount") == null)
{
    detail.Add(new XAttribute("ProductCount", "1"));
}
```

Comment: I tried but no luck :-(   Tried both the options below                detail.Add(new XAttribute("ProductCount", "1"));                      detail.Add(new XAttribute(_ns + "ProductCount", "1"));

Comment: @rs If it is the namespace then you also have to use `_ns + ` in the `if()` statement.

Comment: Thanks all for responses, I figured out I missed to Save the document.